"A 64-bit OS is required for <Windows App>" although a 64-bit wine prefix is active
I've been trying to install a windows application via wine with wine SteelSeriesGG75.1.0Setup.exe but every time I try to do so i get the following window: 1.
After a bit of research i tried to create a 64-bit wine prefix but the problem is still there. I also tried what the first answer did in this post (installing winehq-stable and hacking in a symlink):winetricks wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "" error

You've provided no OS & release details; what Ubuntu product & release are you using?

According to the SteelSeries GG Utility 75.1.0 64-bit website:

When it comes to the installation steps, first check that that all system characteristics are supported; even though other platforms might also be compatible, we do not recommend you apply the software on OSes other than the specified ones.

The SteelSeriesGG75.1.0Setup.exe  file is a general-purpose driver and management suite for the entire ecosystem of SteelSeries products. In general you cannot use Wine to install Windows drivers in Linux. In particular the website referred to by the link in this answer warns its readers that this particular Windows driver is not compatible with other operating systems.

As a starting point install playonlinux which is a graphical front end and makes installation much easier. However, even then I have always found program installations problematic.
If possibly it is generally a good idea to create a new PREFIX for each progam you install. Certainly until you perfect an install.
When not using playonlinux I put the command lines into a bash script to help manage things.  (Program.sh) and set it to run.
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
but check your system is up-to-date first.
Some examples of running a wine program without playonlinux: -
Configure
This will create a new prefix environment of the name in WINEFPREFIX
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winecfg
WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine64 exec winecfg

Example program
Installing is similar to this only you run the install program (this is a trial program) rather than the target.
WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/EXX2_340 exec wine '/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/EXX2_340/drive_c/Program Files/Exxx Txxxx Sxxxxxxx x/bin/win_x86/exxxxxxxxxx.exe' 

After you have installed you will probably have to configure it. This is when your problems really start.
The following shows what is available to install: -
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winetricks list

The following is installing dotnet45 using winetricks playonlinux has its own methods for this: -
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winetricks dotnet45

Good luck
